# NoClassDefFound when running from cmd but not Eclipse

Tags: java, command-line, execution, noclassdeffounderror

I know I'll feel like a tard when I figure this one out.  I'm trying to do a very simple client/server and run it from the command line.  It runs fine from Eclipse, but not from cmd.  Here's the client:

```
package com.mycompany.pdr.client;

import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
public class SimpleClientSend {
public static void main(String[] args) {


    String host = "127.0.0.1";
    int port = 11048;
    String dataToSend = "HELLO SERVER";

    System.out.println("> Trying to connect...");
    System.out.println("> Opening connection to server [" + host + ":"
            + port + "]...");

    Socket socket1Connection;
    try {
        socket1Connection = new Socket(host, port);
        System.out.println("> Connected...");
        System.out.println("> Trying to write data... [ " + dataToSend + " ]");
        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(
                socket1Connection.getOutputStream());
        /*
         * Instantiate an OutputStreamWriter object with the optional
         * character encoding. e.g. UTF-8
         */
        OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(bos, "US-ASCII");

        // Writing to server
        osw.write(dataToSend);
        osw.flush();

        System.out.println("> Writing to server done...");

        socket1Connection.close();

    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getLocalizedMessage());
        System.out.println("Unknown Host. Please check if the server is running at the IP & port");
        //e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getLocalizedMessage());
        System.out.println("Could not send data. Giving up.");
        //e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println("> End of connection...");
}
```

}

My directory structure is : `(MyWorkspace)/myProject/com/mycompany/pdr/client`
I run `javac SimpleClientSend.java` from inside the client folder, and I get a class file, no errors.  I run `java SimpleClientSend` and I get a NoClassDefFound message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:  SimpleClientSend (wrong name: com/iai/pdr/client/SimpleClientSend)
```

I've tried using `-cp .` when I run java to follow the suggestions of every other article out there(but what's the point if . is already in my classpath?), I've tried running it from outside the client folder, everything just gives me the same error.  In eclipse, all I had to do was paste the java files into a blank project and it ran.  What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Try running from (MyWorkspace)/myProject

Comment: herp derp me.  Yep.  Write an answer and I'll accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify the full name of your class (including package).

> java com.mycompany.pdr.client.SimpleClientSend

It is important that the base of the structure for your class(es) is included in your class path. Normally . is included, so if you run the command above when your are in myProject it should work.

If you are in another folder you should add the myProject to your class path, such as:

> java -cp ...MyWorkspace/myProject com.mycompany.pdr.client.SimpleClientSend

The ... of course is since I don't know your full path.